Problemas de renderización con Flatlist u otros elementos que incluyan Scroll
Tengo una aplicación con un sistema de tabs desarrollado usando Expo Router. Dentro de una de las tabs, tengo configurado un Redirect desde la ruta raíz de la tab hacia una subruta específica. A continuación se detalla el código involucrado:
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";

export default function Index() {
    return <Redirect href='/favorites' />
}

El código de favorites es el siguiente:
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ScreenLayout from '../../../components/screen-layout/ScreenLayout'
import { FlatList, View } from 'react-native'
import { Stack } from 'expo-router'
import SwitchCategory from '../../../components/switch-category/SwitchCategory';
import { dataRealEstates, dataVehicles } from '../../../data';
import VehicleCard from '../../../components/vehicle-card/VehicleCard';
import RealEstateCard from '../../../components/real-estate-card/RealEstateCard';

export default function index() {

const [category, setCategory] = useState("VEHICLES");

const vehicles = dataVehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.fav);
const realEstates = dataRealEstates.filter(realEstate => realEstate.fav);

const getElements = (category, item = null) => {
    const elements = {
        VEHICLES: { data: vehicles, component: <VehicleCard item={item} /> },
        REAL_ESTATE: { data: realEstates, component: <RealEstateCard item={item} /> },
    };
    return { data: elements[category].data, component: elements[category].component };
}



return (
    <ScreenLayout withHeader>
        <Stack.Screen
            options={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerTitle: "Favorites",
                headerTintColor: "black",
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                },
                headerBackTitle: "Back",
                headerShadowVisible: false
            }}
        />
        <SwitchCategory
            category={category}
            setCategory={setCategory}
            className="mt-2 mb-4"
        />

        <FlatList
            data={getElements(category).data}
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
            style={{ padding: 5, marginBottom: 20 }}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                getElements(category, item).component
            )}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 15 }} />}
            columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
        />
    </ScreenLayout>
)
}

Cuando navego directamente a la ruta /favorites desde otras tabs o se redirige hacia esta ruta desde la raíz del tab usando Redirect, experimento los siguientes problemas:
Parpadeo o re-renderización constante de los elementos en la FlatList:
Los elementos renderizados (cartas de vehículos o propiedades) parecen parpadear o actualizarse de forma inesperada.
Comportamiento extraño del scroll:
El scroll no es suave, se resetea inesperadamente o regresa al inicio al interactuar con los elementos.
Interacción inconsistente con la lista:
En ocasiones, algunos elementos dejan de responder o el estado del scroll no se conserva al volver a la misma pantalla.


Me acabo de dar cuenta de algo, si yo comento el bloque de código de Stack.Screen, todo se ve genial, el problema viene cuando lo descomento, la lista corta los últimos elementos. El código es este:
export default function index() {


const vehicles = dataVehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.fav);
const realEstates = dataRealEstates.filter(realEstate => realEstate.fav);

const getElements = (category, item = null) => {
    const elements = {
        VEHICLES: { data: vehicles, component: <VehicleCard item={item} /> },
        REAL_ESTATE: { data: realEstates, component: <RealEstateCard item={item} /> },
    };
    return { data: elements[category].data, component: elements[category].component };
}



return (
    <View className="flex-1 h-screen py-3 px-4">
            {/* <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    headerShown: true,
                    headerTitle: "Favorites",
                    headerTintColor: "black",
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                    },
                    headerBackTitle: "Back",
                    headerShadowVisible: false
                }}
            /> */}
        
        <View className="flex-1 items-center">
            <FlatList
                data={getElements(category).data}
                numColumns={2}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
                style={{ padding: 5, marginBottom: 20}}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    getElements(category, item).component
                )}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 15 }} />}
                columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
                ListFooterComponent={<View />}
                ListFooterComponentStyle={{height:20}}
                />
        </View>
    </View>
)
}

Si descomento ese bloque el scroll del FlatList no llega hasta abajo y corta la última fila:

